# An Ideal Correspondence For Twisted C*-Dynamical Sytems?

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, duality-theorems

Back in the 90's, [Nilsen](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-10/S0002-9939-98-04598-5/S0002-9939-98-04598-5.pdf) proved the following result for normal $C^{*}$-dynamical systems:

Suppose that $A$ is a $C^{*}$-algebra, and $G$ is a locally compact group.

1. Let $\delta$ be a coaction of $G$ on $A$.
   Then restriction gives a bijection between
   the $\hat{\delta}$-invariant ideals of $A\rtimes_\delta G$ and the
   $\delta$-invariant ideals of $A$.
2. Let $\alpha$ be an action of $G$ on $A$.
   Then restriction gives a bijection between
   the $\hat{\alpha}$-invariant ideals of $A\rtimes_\alpha G$ and the
   $\alpha$-invariant ideals of $A$.

This establishes a bijective correspondence between the action and dual coaction invariant ideals of $A$ and its crossed product by $G$.  My question is that if we have a system $(A,G,\alpha)$ twisted by a closed normal subgroup $N \lhd G$, does such an analogous result exist?

For instance, if $J \subset A \rtimes_{\alpha|} N$ is an ideal which is $\alpha_N$-invariant ($\alpha_N$ the twisted action), is there a result that states that $J$ must be of the form $J = I \rtimes_{\beta} N$ for $\beta$ some altered version of the action $\alpha$ (or perhaps something entirely different)?

I'm aware of a much more restrictive result of a similar nature from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1908) paper, but I haven't been able to find a direct analog to Nilsen's results to systems twisted by closed normal subgroups $N \lhd G$.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.